# Adding the marker to Google Maps external link

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, hyperlink

I have website that uses Google maps to plot the location of registered businesses. This uses javascript and shows the orange marker to pinpoint the exact location. I'm trying to build a link to the actual google maps page and my code is doing what I want it to except the marker doesn't show up. Is there another peice of code I can add to this to make it show up?

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=<?php echo $business_lat; ?>,<?php echo $business_lon; ?>&z=11&t=m&hl=en-US&mapclient=apiv3" target="_blank">Full Sized Map</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a pin you need the q parameter. It holds **q=latitude+longitude+(url-encoded-text)**

Here is an example of hybrid map with weather - pin at Embassy Suites, map centered on Horseshoe Falls

https://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&ll=43.076,-79.074&spn=0.0212,0.0496&t=h&z=16&q=43.0795N+79.0818W+(Nice%20Hotel)&lci=weather

- **hl**= two letter language code
- **ll**= the map center using coma
  separated +/- values
- **spn**= the viewport span in degrees, works with
  the z parameter
- **t**= map type {**m|k|h|p**}
- **z**= is the zoom factor
- **q**= latitude+longitude+(url-encoded-text), the lat/lon in q have to be
  followed by a letter - **N/S** or **E/W** instead of using +/-
- **lci**= special codes, coma separated - i know of **weather**, **transit_comp**, **com.panoramio.all**
- **layer**= additional layers, e.g. **t** for traffic

Google is changing things with the new Google Maps and a lot of functionality has been removed/replaced. You can check the new Maps Engine here http://mapsengine.google.com/map/